# How do I get access to the album I saved photos like in camera app?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, alassetslibrary

I have saved photos to my customised album in my app using code

```
[library saveImage:self.capturedImg toAlbum:@"FunCam" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];
```

Now I want to retrive all photos saved to that album when user click some button and show them in view like camera app (the default app on iphone) shows

Please help me how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can do that using assets library i don't have any direct link right now but i am sure it can be done using assets library...
google for it you will get it easily

Comment: a demo project is here by using ALAssets https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

Comment: elsimagepickerController is very useful to me after i got images from answered below i asseps thanks to you @Aravindhanarvi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these methods...

```
-(void)loadNewLibraryImages
{
    self.assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Group enumerator Block
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                   {    
                       void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
                       {
                           if (group == nil) 
                           {
                               return;
                           }
                           if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:@"YOUR ALBUM NAME"]) {
                               [self.assetGroups addObject:group];                             
                               [self loadImages];
                               return;
                           }                           

                           if (stop) {
                               return;
                           }

                       };

                       // Group Enumerator Failure Block
                       void (^assetGroupEnumberatorFailure)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {

                           UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Albums Available"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                           [alert show];
                           [alert release];
                       };   

                       // Enumerate Albums
                       ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];        
                       [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                                              usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator 
                                            failureBlock:assetGroupEnumberatorFailure];


                   });


}

-(void)loadImages
{   
    //for (ALAssetsGroup *assetGroup in self.assetGroups) {
//  for (int i = 0; i<[self.assetGroups count]; i++) {

        ALAssetsGroup *assetGroup = [self.assetGroups objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"ALBUM NAME:;%@",[assetGroup valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]);

        [assetGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) 
         {         
         if(result == nil) 
         {
         return;
         }
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[result defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage] scale:1.0 orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[[result valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] intValue]];         

         }];  

//  }
}
```

hope they will help....

Comment: thanks i will give you report about it workings or any error i got. now i am on it to apply in my app

Comment: is that [self loadAssets] is new function that i have to made?

Comment: sry for that that is [self loadImages];

Comment: @Checkit hi . i m getting error in loadNewLibraryImages method . incompatible block pointer at line 5 & from last line 7 . what is assetGroupEnumerator ?