# Ipad Get Images from custom album Device Issue

Tags: ipad, device, photo

Am having a Custom folder in my ipad device. Am using this code to get image from Custom album:

```
self.assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Group enumerator Block
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
   void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
   {
       if (group == nil) {
           return;
       }
       if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:@"Ganesh"]) {
           [self.assetGroups addObject:group];
           [self loadImages];
           return;
       }
       if (stop) {
          return;
       }
   };

   // Group Enumerator Failure Block
   void (^assetGroupEnumberatorFailure)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {
       UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
           initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Albums Available"] 
               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
       [alert release];
   };

    // Enumerate Albums
    self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
    usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
    failureBlock:assetGroupEnumberatorFailure];
});
```

To retrieve all the images from my custom folder I am using this:

```
(void)loadImages {
    ALAssetsGroup *assetGroup = [self.assetGroups objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"asserts group %@",self.assetGroups);
    NSLog(@"ALBUM NAME:;%@",[assetGroup valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]);

    [assetGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
     if(result == nil) {
         return;
     }
     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[result defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage] 
         scale:1.0 orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[[result valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] intValue]];
     NSLog(@"image name%@",img);
     [arrayOfImage addObject:img];
     NSLog(@"arrayOfImage %@",arrayOfImage);
     // [imageToAnimate setImage:img];
     }];
}
```

its working fine when i am running with simulator but not in device: it executes Failure block and Says No Album Available.

Comment: One thing to change is instead of making your library variable property ie instead of synthesize it make it private iVar and try to use it.

Comment: No still it gives the same error.

Comment: It's amazing that you got that error as the same code is working fine on my device.

Comment: ok thanks for your response.  i will check myself and let you know the issue where i did mistake once it works

Comment: And one more small help do you know about this is it possible or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908338/how-to-do-a-ipad-screensaver-application please find and let me know

Comment: Its worked for me, i just switched off my location services in my device, due too this am not able to access my media now its working fine thanks you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Its works fine. I have switched Off my location service due to this am not able to access my media now it works fine.