# How to do a Ipad screensaver application

Tags: image, ipad, screensaver

I Want to do a application like screensaver in ipad. when user clicks the app i want to display my custom folder images to screen saver animation. Instead of photo frame I want to all those in code.  Is it Possible when user clicks my app Its Should redirect to screen saver.

Comment: You know there's a `.` key also and not only `,`?

Comment: I don't know the screen saver animation is possible or not but you can load some nearly 10 to 15 images in scrollview and using timmer show them scrolling as screen saver.:)

Comment: thanks for your reply, No problem i will check with some other way to get it.